# Can someone please help me find this ancedote / experiment?

Tags: behaviorism, behavior

I have a faint memory regarding an ancedote/experiment conducted for a certain psychological behavioral recognition.

My memory recalls:

> It has something to do with a University experiment which invites a certain amount of people and are expected to perform certain tasks and in the end it was something related to identifying a Sociopath or a psychopath from the group. All participants except on in the end comes to the professor / test conductor asking to retrieve some form of prize (collection of money) as the patient fakes all the questions or methods and identifies himself as a sociapath and/or pyschopath.

I realize this is a vague set of information, but if someone could recall this experiment or this particular piece of anecdote, it would be great.